# VBA Run-time Error 1004 "Application-defined or object-defined error" when pasting data from the internet

Tags: excel, vba

```
    Set elemCollection = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("table")


    Range("A1") = "Table 1"


    For t = 0 To (elemCollection.Length - 1)
        For r = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows.Length - 1)
            eRow = Worksheets("All Tables").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                For c = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells.Length - 1)
                    Worksheets("All Tables").Cells(eRow, c + 1) = elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText
                Next c
        Next r
        Cells(eRow + 1, 1) = "Table" & t + 2
        If t = elemCollection.Length - 1 Then
            Cells(eRow + 1, 1) = ""
        End If
    Next t
```

I'm currently working on a code that pulls data from tables online and pastes it into a worksheet. My code pulls the data into a master worksheet where I then filter the required data and put it into different sheets. The code loops and clears the master worksheet to pull data from a new source.

The code seems to be working correctly and loops to get data from about 100 different sources but then I get the run-time error.

I'm not sure why this doesn't occur right away and I'm able to loop many times before this error is generated.

The error occurs on the line

```
Worksheets("All Tables").Cells(eRow,c + 1) = elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it always the same url?

Comment: @QHarr it's a customizable URL so the majority of the URL stays the same but then I enter different parameters to get the different tables

Comment: In `elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText` - can `r` or `c` be `0`?

Comment: Is the problem definitely coming from the rhs of the assignment i.e. elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText  ?

Comment: I don't know which side the error is coming from